# How to take percentage rank of specific rows on conditional?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, percentage

I want to convert some data into percentage ranks however how can I do this so that it only takes percentage ranks of rows when the value of another column is in that same row?

My data:

```vb
821073  4086    woodland
1367182 8483    woodland
774315  3908    greenspace
3155757 9229    greenspace
2298996 9195    greenspace
1133531 5386    greenspace
1839304 6111    woodland
642198  3109    artificial_forest
642198  3109    artificial_forest
9727658 26260   artificial_forest
517463  2776    artificial_forest
3082246 8345    forest
1043860 6873    forest
1851161 5790    forest
762000  3633    greenarea
1575599 5980    greenarea
534234  2795    greenarea
1783711 5446    greenarea
```

In this example I want to calculate the average percentage rank of `Area` and `Perimtr` for those values of `Artificial_forest` and `green_area`, I have tried:

```vb
=AVERAGE(PERCENTRANK.INC($F$8:$F$11, $F$15:$F$18,F8, F15))
```

I end up getting repeating values for `woodland, greenspace, forest`, how can I get it so that it only takes the average percentage rank of `artificial_forest` and `greenarea`, where it returns `NA` or `0` elsewhere?

Comment: It is hard to follow. The PERCENTRANK.INC will return a single value. It takes two arguments and one optional argument and you show it with four arguments. AVERAGE will return the average of the single result from PERCENTRANK.INC, so it is doing nothing. Can you screenshot your ranges, so that they are better understood? If I am guessing, I would say that you need to nest an IF like this : `=PERCENTRANK.INC(IF(OR($C$2:$C$19={"greenarea","artificial_forest"}),$A$2:$A$19),A2,2)`

Comment: Showing us the expected result would also be useful.

Comment: @markfitzpatrick - agreed; the use of the word 'average' threw me a little - especially given OP's formulation which suggests calculating the metric (percentrank) *in relation* to a given value - one can only assume relative to the first occurrence in the filtered array, but even this assumption is questionable i.e. *=AVERAGE(PERCENTRANK.INC($F$8:$F$11, $F$15:$F$18,**F8**, **F15**))* - I've gone with the only thing that makes sense - returning an array as well as an average over this array (specific values can be retrieved using an index on the array)... let's see what OP thinks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### REVISED SOLN

Screenshots/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98UeUvMsc48bu8L4b?e=66qUHM) refer:

Given Office 365 available (per comment @Stackbeans, t-19hrs), a cleaner way to incorporate both *percentranks* within an array is as follows (screenshot, here refer):

[image: PercentRank as array using filter]

```
=SORT(IFERROR(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER(B4:C21,$D$4:$D$21=$G$4),FILTER(B4:C21,$D$4:$D$21=$G$4)),""),,1)
```

---

[image: Direct calculation of averages without displaying percentrank array]

Averages can be determined directly without reproducing this 'array/spill-type' equation as follows:

*Area*

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(SORT(IFERROR(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER(B4:C21,$D$4:$D$21=$G$4),FILTER(B4:C21,$D$4:$D$21=$G$4)),""),,1),0,1))
```

*Perimeter*

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(SORT(IFERROR(PERCENTRANK.INC(FILTER(B4:C21,$D$4:$D$21=$G$4),FILTER(B4:C21,$D$4:$D$21=$G$4)),""),,1),0,2))
```

---

**OR** if the array is to be reproduced and displayed within excel, then this simplifies formula for the average somewhat:

[image: Simplified eqn for average 'perimtr' PercentRank]

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(R3#,0,2))
```

(use `average(index(r3#,0,1))` for area)

---

---

### BONUS

To include validation list drop-down (screenshot below refers)

1. Create lookup list e.g. `=UNIQUE(D4:D21)` in cell N3
2. Select Name Manager in main ribbon, Formulas section:

[image: Name Manager]

3. In the pop-up GUI, select 'new', enter a name (here, 'Name_Lookup') and a reference equation (here, `= $N$3#`) noting the final # which makes this a dynamic range applicable to 'spill-type' ranges/arrays...

[image: Specifying name and formula reference for new named range]

4. Hit 'Close' to return to first window of pop-up, and check the range of the resulting named range by clicking the small upward arrow on the right/bottom near the equation bar in the Gui:

[image: upward arrow, named range GUI, main screen]

[image: check desired range selected appropriately]

5. Create a validation list: cell G5: type alt + d + L (sequentially, releasing one button before depressing next).  see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249) for more info re validation lists...
6. First window of pop-up GUI, select list from drop down menu and enter corresponding reference formula: `= Name_Lookup`, like so:

[image: Data Validation to create drop-down lookup in Excel]

7. Highlight cell different colour (not essential, but makes sheet more user-friendly for others)...

---

---

### ORIGINAL SOLN

Screenshot/[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j98UMIzGp_2TVedS6t?e=151Uwi) refer.

*I consider 'area' alone - this can easily be extended to perimtr in the same fashion.*

To return the array of values corresponding to the *percentrank* for each level of the filtered result, use:

```
=SORT(IFERROR(PERCENTRANK.INC(IF($D$4:$D$21=$G$4,B4:B21,""),IF($D$4:$D$21=$G$4,B4:B21,"")),""),,1)
```

To calculate the average *percentrank* for values in this array, use:

```
=AVERAGE(IFERROR(PERCENTRANK.INC(IF($D$4:$D$21=$G$4,B4:B21,""),IF($D$4:$D$21=$G$4,B4:B21,"")),""))
```

[image: Array - percentrank]

[image: Average - percentrank]

---

**Notes**

- *Lookup feature requires Office 365 compatible version of Excel.  Not an essential feature (was not requested) so assuming this can be ignored if no access to aforementioned Excel version...*
- To retrieve individual values within array, use `=INDEX(SORT(IFERROR(PERCENTRANK.INC(IF($D$4:$D$21=$G$4,B4:B21,""),IF($D$4:$D$21=$G$4,B4:B21,"")),""),,1),I1)` where the final component (I1 = 1,2,..) represents the (ordered) rank of said indexation..

---

Comment: A question on the look-up features - I am using the latest microsoft office on outlook. Can this look-up feature be implemented? As I have tried copying your code above and implementing it within my dataset, though it fails, however when I copy chunks of my data and paste it into the excel spreadsheet you have provided it works wonderously.

Comment: I am fairly new to excel syntax but you mention that I can take the percent rank of both area and perimtr, how can this be done? For your first code, I have tried to include it within the `Percentrank.inc` IF statement, however I get a spill.

Comment: See revised soln-  upvote/downvote and accept answer (or other answer) to help future users, ta